# Laravel data order in json column

Tags: laravel, query-builder, laravel-7

I am using Laravel 7.

I am having some problems with sorting while using Laravel 7.

To put it briefly. My table has a json column.

Example column name: "jsonData" json data:

```
$data1 =
{
"rank":12,
"value":"test",
}

$data2 =
{
"rank":105,
"value":"test-2",
}
```

According to these data, the following query is made.

```
DB::table('tablename')->orderBy('jsonData->rank', 'ASC')->get();
```

While the output I get should be 12 - 105, normally from small to large. When I print the data here, it becomes 105 - 12.

Another example of sorting like this:

```
1
1
10
100
108
113
12
120
1231885
13631
144
```

You may have noticed how absurd this is. I have done a lot of research on how to solve this. But I could not come to a conclusion.

Comment: I have tried to order by my json field and it works for me.

Comment: Can you inser ss? Why I'm gettik response like this?

Comment: I have the same issue! It does sort but alphabetically not numerically :/